# Returning a specific value from a string

Tags: excel-formula

```
2.375;26.375;0.743|98.375;26.375;0.743|98.375;2.375;0.743|2.375;***2.375***;0.743|2.375;26.375;0.743555
```

I'm trying to return the second value equaling `2.375` after the 3rd `"|"`. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: searching is the best way

Comment: Is it always the second after the third `|`?

Comment: I finally figured out how to manipulate this formula to get it to work, though I admit I'll need to study this more in depth to understand why it works.  If there's a easier way to write this I would appreciate an example   =TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A6,FIND("_",SUBSTITUTE(A6,";","_",7))+1,
LEN(A6)),";",REPT(" ",LEN(A6))),LEN(A6)))

Answer (score 0):

Asuming the string is in cell A1 (and the numbers are always 5 chars in length), the following formula will work:

```
 =MID(A1,FIND(";",A1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1,5)
```

OR - to handle any length number you can do this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND(";",A1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1,FIND(";",A1,FIND(";",A1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1)+1)+1)+1)+1)-FIND(";",A1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1,FIND("|",A1)+1)+1)+1)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula will bring the second number after the third `|` regardless of size.

```
=--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"|",REPT(" ",999)),3*999,999)),";",REPT(" ",999)),999,999))
```

[image]

---

We can easily make this formula dynamic:

```
=--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A4,"|",REPT(" ",999)),(C1-1)*999+1,999)),";",REPT(" ",999)),(C2-1)*999+1,999))
```

This will allow you to specify the group and the sequence in that group to return the desired number.

[image]